# Search the recently accepted answers

Tags: support, feature-request, search, accepted-answer

Just want to know if there is an *accepted answers* tab sorted by newest activities.

Though, we do have a tab for the *unanswered questions* sorted by newest activities and a *my tags* tab for faster reference.

[image: unanswered]

*Feature Request:*

[image: answered/unanswered]

[image: accepted]

Similarly, is there any *Answered Questions* tab/workaround? Or, are there any search tips to find the newly *accepted answers* sorted by *newest activities* or *my tags* or *votes*?

Comment: It makes more sense to look for *unanswered* questions..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can search for `hasaccepted:yes`. Then you can select one of the tabs to sort by [newest](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=hasaccepted%3ayes), [votes](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=hasaccepted%3ayes), or [active](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=active&q=hasaccepted%3ayes).

From [How do I search?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) page in Help Center:

> #### Boolean Operators
>
> The following search operators can be used with values of yes/no, true/false, or 1/0 (each pair behaves the same):
>
> - `hasaccepted`: yes/true/1 returns only questions that have accepted answers; no/false/0 returns only questions with no accepted answers.

Comment: for specific tags, this should suffice, [***Example here***](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=+%5Bc%23%5D%5Bstring%5D%5Bregex%5D+hasaccepted%3Ayes) :)